# Reading a Text file into an Array?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Im trying to make a contact book by storing the contacts in a text file. For example lets say I have two strings called first name and surname, and in the text file I have a first name and on the next line a surname. This is currently the code I have but im not sure what I need to do in the do loop, how do I read a line, insert it in string xxx, read the next line and store it in string yyy?

```
    public Contacts[] getAllContacts()
    {

        List<Contacts> theContactList = new List<Contacts>();

        string file_name = "Contacts.txt";
        string textLine = "";

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(file_name) == true)
        {
            System.IO.StreamReader objReader;
            objReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(file_name);


            do
            {
                objReader.ReadLine() + "\r\n";

            } while (objReader.Peek() != 1);

        }
        if (theContactList.Count > 0)
        {
            return theContactList.ToArray();

        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }


    }
```

I will also need to be able to store multiple contacts and more fields, such as address, phone number etc in the text file.

Comment: Can you also explain what "Contacts" is datatypewise? (in the code example....it is hard to read in the text example)

Comment: @Thomas Sorry, It's another class that contains the fields, such as Public string surname, Public string first_name

Comment: Have you had a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezwyzy7b.aspx?

Comment: You dont need to show the entire class just for example: Class Contact { public string surname; public string firstname;} so that ppl see what properties they could need for the answer and how they are called.

Comment: A better way is to store as XML.

Comment: If the number of bytes stored is needed to be minimal xml would be too byte heavy there and a plain text file better but yepp depending on the exact application requirements in most cases storing it in a xml instead of a plain text file is better as that allows to see which line is what (instead of hoping that never a blank line is inserted at the wrong place or one line not being inserted as that would wrong all the data afterwards in a plain text file without infos in it what the line represents and to which contact it belongs).

Answer (score 2):

Under the presumption that there are ALWAYS 2 lines there and they have the same order the following code could work there:

```
public Contacts[] getAllContacts()
{

    List<Contacts> theContactList = new List<Contacts>();

    string file_name = "Contacts.txt";
    string textLine = "";
    bool firstNameLine = true;

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(file_name) == true)
    {
        System.IO.StreamReader objReader;
        objReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(file_name);
        Contact newContact;

        do
        {
            textLine = objReader.ReadLine();
            if (firstNameLine)
            {
                newContact = new Contact();
                newContact.firstName = textLine;
            }
            else
            {
                newContact.sureName = textLine;
                theContactList.Add(newContact);
            }

            firstNameLine = !firstNameLine;

        } while (objReader.Peek() != 1);

    }
    if (theContactList.Count > 0)
    {
        return theContactList.ToArray();

    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }


}
```

Thus the code usese in this case a boolean variable that defines which line read is used to fill which string. IF it is more than 2 lines (more than 2 strings) then an integer variable would be needed (which is increased by +1 and then resetted when the last line needed is read) and instead of the if a switch statement.

Answer (score 2):

Probably better off using XML or CSV file, or even just a text file but with each "Contact" on the same line and parse them out.

The following code will do what you want though.

```
 public Contacts[] GetAllContacts()
    {
        List<Contacts> contacts = new List<Contacts>();
        const string filePath = "Contacts.txt";

        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
            {
                do
                {
                    Contacts contact = new Contacts();
                    contact.FirstName = sr.ReadLine();
                    contact.Surname = sr.ReadLine();
                    contacts.Add(contact);

                } while (sr.Peek() != -1);
            }
        }

        return contacts.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Have to say that is less complicated than my idea (same asumption as I made with both lines always being present) thus +1

Answer (score 1):

```
 while (objReader.Peek() != -1)
 {
     theContactList.Add(new Contact() { Firstname = objReader.ReadLine(), SurName = objReader.ReadLine()});
 }
```

using an initializer list. (obviously making assumptions on the `Contact` classes members)

Comment: What does the { } do in this combination? (the{} after new Contact)

Comment: an object initializer list. (i previously forgot to add the property names.)

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
string [] file_array = File.ReadAllLines("path");
```

**PS :**  `using System.IO;`
this function reads an entire file and store its lines in array you can edit the arrays lines and then use

`File.WriteAllLines("path",file_array);`

to put them back in the file .